Solution or upper bound for "geometric-type" series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(2^k a \,C^{2^k a/2}\right)^{-1}$
How can I find a closed form solution for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(2^k a \,C^{2^k a/2}\right)^{-1}$, for fixed $C>1$ and $a>1$?
Clearly the sum is finite. However, I need to evaluate this sum so I can take a limit wrt a different variable ($a$ is a function). A reasonably tight upper bound would also be acceptable.
Any help is much appreciated.

Yeah, such series are generally difficult to write. Even a simple $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{2^k}$ are hard to get closed formula results.

I was afraid of that. Any ideas for a reasonable upper bound?

Well it's less than $-\frac{1}{2a} \log(1 - C^{-a})$ but that's not very tight.

Can you elaborate on where that came from @AntonioVargas?

Sure, let me type up a quick answer.

For $0 < x < 1$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^k}}{2^k} &= \sum_{n = 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, \ldots} \frac{x^n}{n} \\
& < \sum_{n = 2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots} \frac{x^n}{n} \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{2k} \\
& = -\frac{1}{2} \log\!\left(1-x^2\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Set $x = C^{-a/2}$ and multiply by $1/a$ to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(2^k a C^{2^k a/2}\right)^{-1} < -\frac{1}{2a} \log(1 - C^{-a}).
$$
